# Spring MVC form http params to model object map member variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I struggled to name this question.  The problem I'm trying to solve is very similar to that described [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) but instead of a list of beans I want to submit http request params that represent a map in the model object and let the framework (Spring) take care of building the map from the http request params.  Can anyone advise as to best practice/cleanest way to do this please?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Currently I pass two String arrays that I then convert these into a map before saving into the model object.  I think there must be a nicer way to do this.

I am using Spring MVC and Freemarker for view rendering.

Illustrative code:

model object:

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> barMap;
    // other member variables...
}
```

View fremarker template:

```
<#list foo.barMap?keys as currKey>
    <tr id="barList_${currKey_index}">
        <td><input name="key" type="text" value="${currKey}"/></td>
        <td><input name="value" type="text" value="${foo.barMap[currKey]}"/></td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo (Model model,
                   @RequestParam(value="key", required=false) String[] keys, 
                   @RequestParam(value="value", required=false) String[] values) {

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Map<String, String> barMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (keys != null && values != null && keys.length == values.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (keys[i] != null 
                && !keys[i].isEmpty() 
                && values[i] != null 
                && !values[i].isEmpty()) {

                barMap.put(keys[i], values[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    foo.setBarMap(map);

    return WebConstants.VIEW_FOO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Karibasappa G C and NimChimsky for their answers that helped me a lot and pointed me in the right direction - I upvoted you both.  I ended up using Spring's @ModelAtribute annotation which makes this very easy and minimal extra code.  Note, the html input field needs to be in a specific format, the name attribute must be of the format mapName[mapKey] and the value attribute is the value you want stored in your map for key mapName[mapKey].

Example Solution:

Model object:

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> barMap;

    public Map<String, String> getTagMap() {
        return tagMap;
    }

    public void setTagMap(Map<String, String> tagMap) {
        this.tagMap = tagMap;
    }
}
```

View Freemarker template:

```
<#if foo ??>
    <#if foo.barMap ??>
        <#list foo.barMap?keys as barKey>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- this input field is for display purposes only -->
                    <input name="tagKey" type="text" value="${tagKey}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- this input field populates the map -->
                    <input name="tagMap[${tagKey}]" type="text" value="${foo.tagMap[tagKey]}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </#list>
    </#if>
</#if>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update (Model model, @ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo) {
    // other code omitted
    return "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use directly map to bind

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo (@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams ,Model model){
}
```

and put getters and setters in Foo for map.

then map gets populated automatically

Comment: the html form will have to be changed aswell though ... otherwise the map won't work

Comment: I am able to get this to work.  But what I'd really like is to populate the Foo object directly with the map from the html form, using Spring's @ModelAttribute tag if possible.  I'm experimenting with how to do this but no joy yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just convert directly to Foo :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo (@RequestBody Foo foo){
}
```

chang ethe form to something like this

```
<input name="${currKey}" type="text" value="${foo.barMap[currKey]}"/>
```

You'l need to match up foo structure in the form, you can view the required by debuggin the outtputed json of `@ResponseBody Foo`

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting this solution to work.  I'm getting a http 415 with message "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ()."